# Работа с датами в DataFrame (начало конец периода)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd 
df= pd.DataFrame({'Data':pd.to_datetime(['2018-12-07', '2019-10-01', '2019-09-26', '2018-10-09', '2018-10-08'])}) 
df

        Data
    0   2018-12-07
    1   2019-10-01
    2   2019-09-26
    3   2018-10-09
    4   2018-10-08
```

Мне нужно добавить новый столбец с датой с измененным периодом (начало года, начало месяца ...), если например брать начало месяца, то должно получиться:

```
          Data         DataNew
    0   2018-12-07    2018-12-01
    1   2019-10-01    2019-10-01
    2   2019-09-26    2019-09-01
    3   2018-10-09    2018-10-01
    4   2018-10-08    2018-10-01
```

Я сделал следующим образом:

```
df['DataNew']=df['Data'].dt.strftime('%Y %m  1 ')

df['DataNew']=pd.to_datetime(df['DataNew'])
```

Но этим способом на большом объеме данных получается очень долго. Пробовал сделать через `Datetime.replace()` или через `dt.round()`, не получается.

Есть ли более эффективное решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [12]: df["DataNew"] = df["Data"] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
        Data    DataNew
0 2018-12-07 2018-12-01
1 2019-10-01 2019-10-01
2 2019-09-26 2019-09-01
3 2018-10-09 2018-10-01
4 2018-10-08 2018-10-01
5 2018-12-31 2018-12-01
```

Comment: если Дата будет 2018.12.31, то он выдает 2019.01.01

Comment: @LesNick, исправил ответ...

Comment: Спасибо теперь работает, а что означает параметр 0 в MonthEnd(0)

Comment: @LesNick, это число добавляемых месяцев

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь субмодулем offsets:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthBegin

print(df) #исходный df

        Data
0 2018-12-07
1 2019-10-01
2 2019-09-26
3 2018-10-09
4 2018-10-08

df.loc[df['Data'].dt.is_month_start, 'new']= df['Data']
df.loc[~df['Data'].dt.is_month_start, 'new']= df['Data'] - MonthBegin() 
print(df)
```

получим:

```
        Data        new
0 2018-12-07 2018-12-01
1 2019-10-01 2019-10-01
2 2019-09-26 2019-09-01
3 2018-10-09 2018-10-01
4 2018-10-08 2018-10-01
```